# Flutter in app purchases with bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

My store is a item on my bottom navigation bar, called as a new class when selected as with my other bottom navigation items. I havent added any navigation pop to these items.

When using the in_app_purchases i have everything working great apart from one small thing, and this is potentially a stupid question but can't find an answer anywhere.

When the purchase dialog is dismissed, either by a purchase being made or the user tapping off the dialog, my navigationbar reverts back to item one with that the corresponding class run and widgets displaying. I want it to stay on the store, i cant find anything in .buyConsumable that can prevent this happening. Apologies for asking if a stupid question, through my flutter journey i've managed to find answers to everything apart from this! Thanks.

Comment: hi, interesting, not sure if the devtools might help https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging

Comment: Figured out it was because I have a seperate unrelated handler for AppLifecycleState. This is to ensure if a user leaves the app, it will be on the homepage when they come back to it. Dismissing the purchase dialog was triggering the AppLifecycleState.resume state and sending the user back to the homepage (1st item on Bottom Navigation Bar). I was so focused on my store and the iap api that i kept missing this...doh.

Comment: Nice discovery!